# Change a recurring meeting in outlook to an "all day" meeting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-365

I have a recurring meeting set up every week on Wednesdays from 9-10am.

I want to change it to an "all day" recurring meeting on Wednesdays, but I can't see how to do that without cancelling the series and recreating it.

When you first create a meeting, it has the "All Day" tickbox available, but that isn't an option in the "Edit Recurrence" screen.

[image: Appointment Recurrent screenshot]

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the Start and End time to 00:00hrs and Duration to 1 day:

[image]